# Where to use dependent: :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose `User` has many `Receipt` and I would like all the instances of `Receipt` to be destroyed when the parent `User` instance gets deleted.

What is the difference between writing:

(1) In `User` model, `has_many :receipts, dependent: :destroy`

(2) In `Receipt` model, `belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> (1) In User model, has_many :receipts, dependent: :destroy

If user is destroyed then its associated receipts will be destroyed as well.

> (2) In Receipt model, belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy

If receipt is destroyed then its parent user will be destroyed, but other associated receipts would not be destroyed but would be orphaned. According to [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to)

> This dependent: option should not be specified when belongs_to is used in
> conjunction with a has_many relationship on another class because of
> the potential to leave orphaned records behind.

Answer (score 1):

(1) In User model, has_many :receipts, dependent: :destroy

Here, If user destroy then all associated receipts will be destroyed

(2) In Receipt model, belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy

Here if Receipt destroyed then belonging user will be destroyed

you can specify the :dependent option with  following three forms:

- :destroy/:destroy_all The associated objects are destroyed alongside
  this object by calling their destroy method
- :delete/:delete_all All associated objects are destroyed immediately
  without calling their :destroy method
- :nullify All associated objects' foreign keys are set to NULL without
  calling their save callbacks